# Creating a UrlHelper like helper class instance per request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to create a helper class which is similar to the UrlHelper class in that it requires an instantiation of the class to be available to the views, but I cant for the life of me work out where UrlHelper is instantiated to become available in the view as @Url, as I would like to do the same thing.

Can anyone enlighten me at all?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do something like this? Please explain so we can find a good solution for the thing you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to?  All I am saying I want to do is to create my own helper which acts like UrlHelper does with regard to being instantiated automagically and being available in all views - thats not exactly an "out there" request, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done this before, but it's something you could try.

Try creating a new class that extends System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage. I don't have the MVC source on this machine, so I can't say exactly how the framework creates this instance for the views, but you may be able to change the base page-type in your Web.config to make MVC create instances of your new type rather than its own type.

You could then add whatever properties you want to that new type and have them accessible in your views.

You'd also have to create a generic for that type: `Your.New.Page.Type<T>`, and declare that as the type in your view (I'm not exactly sure how this is done in Razor):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="Youre.New.Page.Type" %>
```

There's probably a bunch of stuff I'm missing.

See the `pageBaseType` attribute:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>

    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="Your.New.Page.Type, Your.New"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Bingo, this looks like the sort of thing I need to look into, but was having difficulty finding the start point to search for more info :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Controller's UrlHelper is set in the MVC framework itself. Adding another object-level property to the controller available in views would require hacking the framework (if I'm wrong, let me know).

Generally, it's a better idea to create an extension method which returns the object you want in your view. For example:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MyObjectType GetMyObject(this UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        return new MyObjectType();
    }
}
```

To use `GetMyObject()` like this: `@Url.GetMyObject()`, you need to include the namespace in which the extension method is declared in your Web.config:

```
<namespaces>
    <!-- other namespaces will be here -->
    <add namespace="My.Namespace" />
</namespaces>
```

**Update:**
In response to your comment, consider adding non-View specific functionality to your model:

```
@Model.MyObject.GetSomeProperty()
```

Comment: Hanging it off of another helper solves the problem to an extent, but looks and feels extremely hacky in nature - and it also requires that I hang potentially unrelated functionality off of one of the existing helpers, which is what I am trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: @Moo -- I think the idea of the View in MVC is that all functionality of the provided Controller objects should solely deal with the view, which is why so many extensions use the HtmlHelper class: the extensions generally have to do with rendering HTML (which is view-specific). If you need additional functionality not related to the view, you should probably be including that functionality in your model, not your controller.

Comment: ken, so what you are essentially saying is that there is no scope for non-model-specific, non-view-specific extra helper functionality that doesn't sit nicely as an extension method off of one of the existing helpers?  Because thats essentially what I want to do - provide functionality that is non-model-specific and non-view-specific, but I don't feel comfortable hanging it off an unrelated currently available helper

Answer (score 2):

<s>Create your helper like this:</s>

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string SomeUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        return "someUrl";
    }
}
```

And in your view you can reference it like this:

```
@Url.SomeUrl()
```

If they are in different namespaces, you need to have this at the top of your view:

```
@using YourContainingExtNameSpace
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to extend the `UrlHelper` class, you could make a separate class like this:

```
public class UrlGenerator
{
    public string MakeUrl()
    {
        return "someUrl";
    }
}
```

As long as you have this reference in your View, you can call this method like so:

```
@{
    UrlGenerator ug = new UrlGenerator();
    ug.MakeUrl();
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I asked and not what I want to do - I want to create a helper that acts like UrlHelper in that it has a new instance per request made available as @Url, not extend UrlHelper with additional functionality.

Comment: Not really, because I specifically need UrlGenerator to be an instance of a class, not a static class.  Thanks for the edit tho :)

Comment: @Moo :) See my edit again.  Is that what you're looking for?  I basically just made the class non static and instantiated it in View code.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I want, but I don't want to have to specifically do the instantiation everywhere - UrlHelper gets instantiated somewhere else and made available, which is the approach I am trying for here.  It makes sense because it just makes the functionality available without having to set it up.  However, it doesnt seem that you can tie in to the way UrlHelper does it without digging into the guts of MVC :(

Comment: @Moo Ahhh, I see what you're saying.  `Url` is a property of the `WebViewPage` class.  In other words, you can access the `Url` property of that `WebViewPage` instance (through the View, because that is the current context).  The Controller is the same way.  It has a `Url` property (of type `UrlHelper`) that is part of the `Controller` base class.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is creating a extension on the UrlHelper and implement your needs there.

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string CustomThingy(this UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        //Do your custom stuff in here and add extra parameters if you need them
        //For example some Func or Expression or more simpler a string
    }
}
```

However the question still is what would you like to do with it, because in some cases it would be easier to write an AjaxExtension or an HtmlExtension. That was the reason for my initial comment on your question. All provide you access to different concepts.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string CustomThingy(this HtmlHelper urlHelper)
    {

    }
}

public static class AjaxExtensions
{
    public static string CustomThingy(this AjaxHelper urlHelper)
    {

    }
}
```